# Difference between signing a XML message using dsig:Signature and TLS Client Certificate

Tags: xml, security, ssl, digital-signature, xml-signature

I realise this question may be a bit vague or I may be using incorrect terminology, that is because I am trying to get to grips with this stuff :).

I have a requirement to implement digital signing of a XML message by using a dsig:Signature section. I think I understand this process; I will use a private key to sign it which will guarantee to the recipient that it was me who sent the message *and* that no one has tampered with it.

Am I right that this is different from implementing TLS Client Certificates but the goal is the same? (because TLS is transport level, right?) Would implementing Client Certificates be easier? Is one better than the other?

Many thanks for your reply,

Martijn

**Update 1:**

I think another difference is that using a TLS Client certificate the whole message will be encrypted, whereas with digital signing the message itself will be plain text, containing a signature section.

Comment: They are not interchangeable. If you want to comply with XML security standards, you do one. If you want to connect to an SSL/TLS server that requires client authentication, you do the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're comparing message-level security with transport-level security. Although they have similarities, they have different purposes.

Using TLS protects the communication from being seen and altered by intermediate parties. The X.509 certificate on the server side guarantees that the messages sent to it can only be read by the server with this private key and that what it sends comes from the server with this private key. This could *loosely* be considered as signing by the server and encrypting for the server with the X.509 certificate, although it really applies only to the TLS handshake messages, not the application data that's exchanged afterwards. (I'm leaving out the fact that you get symmetric encryption of the channel anyway, whether or not any party has presented a certificate; it's important to have at least the server use a certificate so that the client knows what it's communicating with instead of communicating with a potential man-in-the-middle).
When you add a client certificate to this, the client also signs the TLS messages it has exchanged during the handshake.

When you use both client and server certificates, you could (carefully) draw an analogy with message-level security, in that the messages that are signed and encrypted are the TLS handshake messages that are used to established the TLS channel.

However, there are big differences with message-level security (e.g. XML-DSig and XML-Enc).

Firstly, one of the features of message signing (XML-DSig) is auditing, so that you can keep records of what's been said. It's not specifically time-limited. That's much harder to do even if you've recorded the TLS packets. With modern cipher suites in SSL/TLS that use DHE (Diffie-Hellman ephemeral mode), even if you have the server's private key, you can't necessarily decipher the channel if you have recorded all its packets (without further knowledge of the DHE mechanism).

Secondly, in terms of implementations, XML-DSig tends to be done at the application level, whereas TLS tends to be done by the server connector. The difference can be blurred depending on the conditions of deployment, but TLS is about communicating with the machine/container rather than the application behind them. Typically, the TLS certificate will be set up on a Java container or at the WCF level, whereas the certificate used for XML-DSig will be used by the webapp/application running behind. There may be different people or procedure in charge there.

(You're also right that if you're using XML-DSig without XML-Enc, you're not encrypting the data.)

Answer (score 1):

So far you are comparing apples to oranges.

XML data can be signed in many ways, for example using XMLDSig standard and X.509 certificate (it's possible to use other key types in XMLDSig as well). Signature certifies the authorship of the document (well, to some extent of course).

TLS stands for Transport Layer Security and is used to *encrypt* (not sign) the data while in transfer. It has nothing to do with XML specifically.  TLS uses X.509 certificates as well, but you can't use the same certificate for XMLSDig and TLS cause the certificates need to have specific purposes (key usage field).

I suggest that you take some book on PKI ( I always recommend [Rsa Security's Official Guide to Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072254947) for it's simplicity) and read it attentively.

Comment: TLS with client certificates can effectively be considered as having the client "sign" the communication. The parties that present a certificate effectively "sign" the data they send, by signing the handshake messages: TLS isn't just about encryption, it's also about protecting data integrity and binding to the remote party's identity.

Comment: @Eugene Many thanks for your answer and the book, I will read up on this.

Comment: @Bruno Thanks! So basically TLS with client certificates provides everything the XML signature does (integrity and identity) and on top of that it provides encryption (so message contents cannot be read on the wire)?

Comment: Strictly, the two parties to the TLS communication are signing (and encrypting) the messages they send, but neither end can prove this to anyone else; the signatures aren't retained on the message. Moreover, it's possible to have keys that can do both signing and TLS, provided both usages are permitted. I'd imagine that it would be more common to keep those separated though; the key for TLS is owned by the server operator and not the webapp owner (assuming they're different).

Comment: @martijn_himself no, TLS doesn't guarantee identity of the data signer. It guarantees that nobody alters the data in transit, but doesn't say anything about original signer.

Comment: @Bruno: perhaps, but I wouldn't push the analogy too far. If you look carefully at the RFC, not very much is signed in a non-repudiable manner, even in the handshake. Every record after the handshake is MAC'ed, which is like a signature, but it has one very bad property: either side of the communication can forge these MACs, so non-repudiation is lost.