# Docusign Connect API authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, docusignapi

I have two questions.
How to decide which one of the following is best for me to choose as my authentication method?

1. Sign Message with X509 Certificate
2. Require Mutual TLS

How to implement the two authentication methods?
I am using a Rails 4 app as my Connect API endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's best for you will depend on your situation and priorities.

> Sign Message with X509 Certificate

This can be used to verify or prove the source of the message. In this case DocuSign. This could be useful for auditing purposes.

> Require Mutual TLS

With Mutual Auth TLS both the sender and the receiver verify each other using certificates. So the receiver knows the communication has been initiated by DocuSign, and the DocuSign service verifies that the certificate used by the receiver is as per configuration settings in the DocuSign console. The aim here is to prevent a Man-in-the-middle type attack where the communication could be intercepted and modified/recorded by an attacker.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153568/difference-between-signing-a-xml-message-using-dsigsignature-and-tls-client-cer) answer talks about the differences in more detail.

I think the key point is both approaches solve different problems, depending on your situation you may require one, both or neither.

Regarding implementation, TLS is typically done at a server level, so may require only configuration and no application code. XML signing on the other hand is typically done within the application itself.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Could you please tell me how to implement Mutual TLS for my rails app? What are the things that i need to do on my application?

Comment: What Application Server/Container are you deploying your app to? Are you fronting it with a Web Server too?

Comment: I am using Apache Phusion Passenger

Comment: I don't know how you would implement Mutual TLS in Apache Phusion Passenger standalone. However, if you integrated Phusion Passenger with Apache HTTP Server or the nginx web server the Mutual TLS could be done there. Here is a nginx example: http://nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi